# Graph API Facebook for private profile, no likes, no reactions and no comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In the Graph API Facebook, for private profile, no more likes, reactions and comments appear. Is there a way to request them again?
For the pages must be administrators, but for private profiles?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to request them again?

No, there isn’t. You can only get those made by the current user who’s access token you are using, everything else will be hidden from your app.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version3.0#comments-edge:

> When read with a User access token, the /comments edge returns empty data for the following nodes: Album, Photo, Post, Video

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version3.0#reading:

> The following edges and fields, when read with a User access token, return only the current user and only if applicable. […]

---

Regarding the comments, what is says does not seem to be strictly true - I can still see comments made by myself when requesting /me/feed?fields=comments; but everybody else’s don’t show up.

Comment: This is very sad news for me. I spent the last few months developing an app that was based on that.